# How do I save data into MySql database using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, mysql-workbench

I am trying to insert data into MySql database but I am not getting any errors. I have already tested out the sql query but it works in the mysql workbench but it not working in the project codes.

```
protected void uploadImagesBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CMSconnectionString"].ToString();

        string name = ImgNameTB.Text;
        string desc = imgDescriptionTB.Text;
        string date = uploadDateTB.Text;
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CMSconnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO fyp_cms.images (ImageName, ImageDescription, UploadDate) VALUES (@imgname, @imgdesc, @imgUploadDate)"))
            {
                using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imgname", name);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imgdesc", desc);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imgUploadDate", date);
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

**.aspx file**

```
 <div class="card-body">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="inputEmail4">Image Name</label>
                                <asp:TextBox class="form-control" ID="ImgNameTB" name="imageName" placeholder="Name" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="inputEmail4">Date</label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="uploadDateTB" class="form-control" type="Date" name="imageuploadDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputAddress">Description</label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="imgDescriptionTB" class="form-control" name="imageDescription" placeholder="eg. Open House 2021" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <label for="inputAddress">Select Image</label>

                        <div class="form-group col-mb-4">
                            <div class="custom-file">
                                <%--<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01">
                                <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile02" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon02">Choose file</label>--%>
                                <asp:FileUpload ID="ImageFileUpload1" runat="server" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <label for="inputAddress">Select File</label>
                        <div class="input-group mb-4">
                            <div class="custom-file">
                                <%--<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01">
                                <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile02" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon02">Choose file</label>--%>
                                <asp:FileUpload ID="VideoFileUpload2" runat="server" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <label for="inputAddress">Select Videos</label>
                        <div class="input-group mb-4">
                            <div class="custom-file">
                                <%--<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01">
                                <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile02" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon02">Choose file</label>--%>
                                <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <asp:Button ID="uploadImagesBtn" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary" Text="Upload" OnClick="uploadImagesBtn_Click" />
            </div>
```

Those above are my codes, I am not sure what is the error as I have alr added an onclick function on the upload button

Comment: Can you try wrapping it all in a try..catch block and step through it to see if you are actually causing an exception ?

Answer (score 0):

****set form Post,enctype and button type Submit.
actually you are submitting file. form is not submitting without form enctype****

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">


<asp:Button ID="uploadImagesBtn" type="submit" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary" Text="Upload" OnClick="uploadImagesBtn_Click" />
```